# bash: apt-get: command not found (on ubuntu docker image)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt-get

Inside an ubuntu docker container based on this image:

```
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
```

I am trying to run `apt-get install` (yes I am aware I should build a new image from a dockerfile but still trying to understand why it fails) but get the below error:

```
# uname -a
Linux 217054a34cb7 5.3.0-55-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:47:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# apt-get install
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

From what I can see the above is ubuntu so whats up with `bash: apt-get: command not found`?

**UPDATE:**

Its CentOS:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
```

So it works with:

```
yum install openssl
```

But why does

```
# uname -a
Linux 217054a34cb7 5.3.0-55-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:47:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

return `Ubuntu SMP`?

Comment: Which ubuntu image are you using? I'm unable to reproduce this using Docker for Mac with the latest ubuntu image `sha256:1d622ef86b138c7e96d4f797bf5e4baca3249f030c575b9337638594f2b63f01`

Comment: Please share your Dockerfle

Comment: `uname` says your host is running an Ubuntu-built kernel, but doesn't say anything at all about what package manager or distribution (if any) the image is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elasticsearch image isn't Ubuntu based.

Docker isn't emulating a kernel, instead it uses the (already running) kernel of the host system in every container, so the kernel information in every container will be the kernel information of the host. Your host is Ubuntu, but the image isn't.